# 3 JS code blocks in a js file and never repeat a block if placed 3 times in same html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 3 blocks of code lets call it `block-1` , `block-2` and `block-3` in the file `script.js`. I called `script.js` 3 times in the same html page. I need to create condition of write function in such a way that each block will be executed just once. For example in the first call only `block-1` will be executed in the second call `block-2` and in third call `block-3` will be executed.

I have written the following condition. its working for 2 blocks but i neeed it for three.

```
if (typeof first === 'undefined') {
        // FIRST BLOCK

    var first = 0;
    var second = 1;       
}

if (second == 2) {

    // SECOND BLOCK

}
second = 2;
```

How Can  i do that?

Comment: why do you call the script 3 times in the same page?

Comment: I need to put 3 passback ad tags behind a single ad tag. And in the single page 3 ad positions are there.

Comment: Use functions...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var i=0;
function callthis(){
i++;
if(i==1){
//first
}
if(i==2){
//second
}
if(i==3){
//third
}
}
```